# Show that $F^n$ is a strict contraction.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f\in C(a,b)$ and $K \in C([a,b] \times [a,b])$ where $a<b$. Define an operator $F(f) = \int_a^tK(t,s)f(s)ds$. Then i need to show that $F^n = F\circ....\circ F$ is a strict contraction for some $n$. I found an upper bound $|F^n(f)-F^n(g)| \leq M^n(t-a)^n\|f-g\|{_\infty}$ where $|K(t,s)| \leq M$ and $f,g \in C(a,b)$, but the constant isnt below one.

My question: Is the approximation too harsh? Any hints?

Comment: So for example $F^2 = F(F(f)) = F(\int_a^tK(t,s)f(s)ds) = \int_a^tK(t,s) \int_a^tK(t,s)f(s) dsds \leq \int_a^tM \int_a^tM\|f\|_\infty dsds = M^2(t-a)^2\|f\|_\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\vert F^2(f)(u)\vert =\left\vert \int_a^u K(u, t) F(f)(t) dt \right\vert
=\left\vert \int_a^u K(u,t) \left( \int_a^t K(t,s) f(s) ds \right) dt \right\vert \leq M^2 \Vert f\Vert_\infty \int_a^u \int_a^t 1 ds dt 
=M^2 \Vert f\Vert_\infty \int_a^u (t-a) dt 
= M^2 \Vert f\Vert_\infty (u-a)^2/2.$$
If you keep iterating (meaning doing induction) you will end up with
$$\vert F^n(f)\vert \leq M^n \Vert f\Vert_\infty (b-a)^n/n!.$$
The factorial is going to beat the polynomial terms and allows you to conclude.

Comment: Obviously thank you :)

Comment: @esmegaforceenergydrink You are welcome :) Glad I could help.